# Application development for iPhone

Tags: iphone

Can I develop iPhone applications using Windows 7? If not, can I install Mac OS X besides Windows 7? Is Mac OS X free? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you serious? You don't know whether Mac OS is free?

Answer (score 2):

- NO
- YES
- NO (but rather cheap, somewhere around 30$ i guess)

Comment: It's $30 only if you've already got OS X ≤10.5. Assuming you follow the EULA.

Comment: Otherwise you'll have to buy the Mac Box Set, which is $169, but also includes iWork.

Answer (score 1):

While samsam glibly answered YES to your second question, the end user license agreement places a bit of a restriction. You *may* install Mac OS X alongside Windows 7, as long as both are on an "Apple-badged computer" (i.e. on a Mac). You may install Windows on any computer you want, but Apple don't allow installation of Mac OS X on non-Apple computers. That said, there's little technology stopping such an installation.

Comment: that of course is completely correct. I didn't go back far enough I guess. Maybe it's also worth mentioning, that there is the possibility to work on a mac and use a virtualized windows 7 running in vmware fusion (or another desktop virtualization software)...

Answer (score 0):

For basic apps you can use Titanium/similar (or at least could, I'm not quite up to date with Apple's current thinking on the matter) and that can be done from Windows, but for more complex apps where the browser just limits you too much (games, etc) you'll really need a Mac/Mac install.

If you want to Hackintosh, I'd still say it's better to get a new PC and do it - one where you know people have had success with those exact components. You could build a pretty decent PC for way cheaper than the equivalent Mac.

It is against the Mac OS T&C's to do Hackintosh, but as with perhaps Jailbreaking they're not doing all they could to prevent it (quite yet anyway...)